# php query execution error when used as method

Tags: php

In my opinion i have a weird problem. The part below works fine

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE 
        ".$table[0]."
    SET 
        p_title = '".$_POST['p_title']."', 
        p_date = '".$_POST['p_date']."' 
    WHERE 
        p_id = '".$_POST['p_id']."'
";
if(!$db->exec($sql)){
    echo($defaults->throwError('MySql error',$sql,implode(":",$db->errorInfo())));
}else{
    $defaults->writeLog($table,$db->lastInsertId(),'update');
}
```

But when i try the code below i get an 'Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in'

```
class Defaults{
    [..]
    public function query($sql){
        if(!$db->exec($sql)){
            echo($defaults->throwError('MySql error',$sql,implode(":",$db->errorInfo())));
        }else{
            $defaults->writeLog($table,$db->lastInsertId(),'update');
        }
    }
    [..]
}
```

and then on my page

```
$defaults = new Defaults();
$defaults->query("
    UPDATE 
        ".$table[0]."
    SET 
        p_title = '".$_POST['p_title']."', 
        p_date = '".$_POST['p_date']."' 
    WHERE 
        p_id = '".$_POST['p_id']."'
");
```

How come?

Ah, it was about the `$db` in the class. However, when i do something like

```
public function query($sql){
    $db = new PDO($dbdata->hostname,$dbdata->username,$dbdata->password);
    if(!$db->exec($sql)){
        echo($defaults->throwError('MySql error',$sql,implode(":",$db->errorInfo())));
    }else{
        $defaults->writeLog($table,$db->lastInsertId(),'update');
    }
}
```

I get a nasty

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' 
with message 'invalid data source name' 
in /class.defaults.php:8 

Stack trace: 
#0 /class.defaults.php(8): PDO->__construct('', NULL, NULL) 
#1 /class.form.php(269): Defaults->query('?????????UPDATE...') 
#2 /module.projectbeheer.edit.php(25): Form->proceed('update', 'p_id', 'rows', Array, Array, '') 
#3 /class.content.php(16): include_once('/path/') 
#4 /administratie.php(72): Content->write('/BraamsArchief/...') 
#5 {main} thrown in /class.defaults.php on line 8
```

Comment: bad guy will kill your database ....your code is vulnerable

Comment: The first snippet has `$db` variable in scope; the second does not. You didn't show the place where it's initialized, but it's actually the key here.

Comment: it's only for backend use for maybe two users who, i assume, are not interested in destroying their own database. But it should be safe, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What happened to $db in the second snippet?

Comment: What happened to $db in the second snippet?

Comment: Yea, the code is very vulnerable, by injecting values into p_id any hacker can gain full access to your database

Comment: Ah, it was about the $db in the class, although that gives me something else, see edit... :(

Comment: using pdo isnt mean you are safe ...even you are not using parametrized query

Comment: Of course, now `$dbdata` is out of scope. I still don't get why you're trying to initialize the connection within the method. How about using Registry (or DI container) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide $db either as a global or as a class property. Otherwise, you cannot access it in the method scope.

So either:

```
public function query($sql) {
    global $db;
    // now you can use $db as you would in global scope
}
```

or else you have to set a class property (e.g. $this->db) with your database connection object and access it using $this->db in your method.

Note that if you use the `global` solution, you will need to ensure that the variable is always called $db when it is initially defined. Otherwise, your method may not be able to find it and you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

$db is accessible from within Defaults?

try adding a `global $db;` within function query